# Extract values from a JSON Array in Presto

Tags: sql, arrays, json, presto, trino

I have a column with JSON arrays like below:

```
{data=[{"name":"col1","min":0,"max":32,"avg":29},
{"name":"col2","min":1,"max":35,"avg":21},
{"name":"col3","min":4,"max":56,"avg":34}]}
```

I'm trying to parse the array and extract specific values based on conditions. For example

value of `"min"` where `"name"="col1"`:   0

value of `"avg"` where `"name"="col3"`:   34

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid one. it should be `{"data":[` not `{data = [`

If JSON is valid ( you can easily fix it in a subquery ), extract data, cast it to array(row) and get values using CASE expressions. I added max() aggregation here to remove NULL records and get all required values in single row, you can use filter instead (for example `where x.name = 'col1'`), depending on what you need:

```
with mydata as (
select '{"data":[{"name":"col1","min":0,"max":32,"avg":29},
{"name":"col2","min":1,"max":35,"avg":21},
{"name":"col3","min":4,"max":56,"avg":34}]}' json
)

select max(case when x.name = 'col1' then x.min end) min_col1,
       max(case when x.name = 'col3' then x.avg end) avg_col3
from mydata
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(
            CAST(
                JSON_EXTRACT(json,'$.data')
                    as ARRAY(ROW(name VARCHAR, min INTEGER, max INTEGER, avg INTEGER))
                 )
          ) as x(name, min, max, avg) --column aliases
```

Result:

```
min_col1    avg_col3
0           34
```

Comment: How the query will be updated in case the array is not stored in any key but directly as the array?

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the above question from [@siraj-alam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5132337/siraj-alam), and extending on the answer by [@leftjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2700344/leftjoin), if the data is a JSON array, i.e.

```sql
with mydata as (
select '[{"name":"col1","min":0,"max":32,"avg":29},
{"name":"col2","min":1,"max":35,"avg":21},
{"name":"col3","min":4,"max":56,"avg":34}]' json
)
```

This query gives the same answer

```sql
select max(case when x.name = 'col1' then x.min end) min_col1,
       max(case when x.name = 'col3' then x.avg end) avg_col3
from mydata
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(
            CAST(
                JSON_EXTRACT(json,'$')
                    as ARRAY(ROW(name VARCHAR, min INTEGER, max INTEGER, avg INTEGER))
                 )
          ) as x(name, min, max, avg) --column aliases
```

```
min_col1    avg_col3
0           34
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the solution mentioned by @mingdinghan as it was the exact solution I was looking for. However, I ended up getting errors.

I made changes to the above code & was successful in getting the solution. Below is the solution if anyone is facing issue with the above code.

```
with mydata as (
select '[{"name":"col1","min":0,"max":32,"avg":29},
{"name":"col2","min":1,"max":35,"avg":21},
{"name":"col3","min":4,"max":56,"avg":34}]' jsonobj
)
select 
    max(case when a.name = 'col1' then a.min end) min_col1,
    max(case when a.name = 'col3' then a.avg end) avg_col3
from mydata
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(
            CAST(json_parse(jsonobj) as array(ROW(name VARCHAR, min INTEGER, max INTEGER, avg INTEGER))
                 )
          ) as x(a)
```

Result is still the same as above.